# проблема с импортированием некоторых файлов в github desktop

Tags: github

> warning: in the working copy of 'Assets/images/npc-2.meta', LF will be
> replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it

вот такие ошибки выскакивают при коммите. Не понимаю в чём проблема.

Ничего пока не делал с этой проблемой, потому что не понял что делать :)

Comment: https://htmlacademy.ru/blog/git/konec-stroki